# POST request using Python flask - postman

Tags: python, flask, post, postman

My code is as below

```
# Cafe TABLE Configuration
class Cafe(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(250), unique=True, nullable=False)
    map_url = db.Column(db.String(500), nullable=False)
    img_url = db.Column(db.String(500), nullable=False)
    location = db.Column(db.String(250), nullable=False)
    seats = db.Column(db.String(250), nullable=False)
    has_toilet = db.Column(db.Boolean, nullable=False)
    has_wifi = db.Column(db.Boolean, nullable=False)
    has_sockets = db.Column(db.Boolean, nullable=False)
    can_take_calls = db.Column(db.Boolean, nullable=False)
    coffee_price = db.Column(db.String(250), nullable=True)
```

## HTTP POST - Create Record

```
app.route('/add_cafe', methods=['POST', 'GET'])


def add_cafe():
    new_data = Cafe(name=request.form.get("name"),
                    map_url=request.form.get("map_url"),
                    img_url=request.form.get("img_url"),
                    location=request.form.get("location"),
                    has_sockets=bool(int(request.form.get("has_sockets"))),
                    has_toilet=bool(int(request.form.get("has_toilet"))),
                    has_wifi=bool(int(request.form.get("has_wifi"))),
                    can_take_calls=bool(int(request.form.get("can_take_calls"))),
                    seats=request.form.get("seats"),
                    coffee_price=request.form.get("coffee_price")),

    new_cafe_json = jsonify(cafe=new_data)
    db.session.add(new_cafe_json)
    db.session.commit()
    return jsonify(result={"Success": "Added successfully"})
```

[image: Screen shot of postman request and response]

I am getting 404 error - not found. Other requests are working fine. Any help. I am a beginner.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you arent decorating the view function correctly.

your code is like this:

```
app.route('/add_cafe', methods=['POST', 'GET'])


def add_cafe():
    new_data = Cafe(name=request.form.get("name"),
    map_url=request.form.get("map_url"),
    .....
```

And it should be like:

```
@app.route('/add_cafe', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def add_cafe():
    your code...
```

It seems that your usage of SQLAlchemy isnt in good shape as well. In the part you add information to `db.session` you should add a Model Instance of the object you want to save, in your code the object is the variable `new_data` like this: `db.session.add(new_data)` and then commit.

Greetings!

Comment: Thank you so much for responding. I made suggested changes (how i missed that @). I still get the following error.

Comment: sqlalchemy.orm.exc.UnmappedInstanceError: Class 'builtins.NoneType' is not mapped

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\LIC\PycharmProjects\RestAPI\venv\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\session.py", line 2566, in add
    state = attributes.instance_state(instance)
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute '_sa_instance_state'

Comment: The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\LIC\PycharmProjects\RestAPI\venv\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2088, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "C:\Users\LIC\PycharmProjects\RestAPI\venv\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2073, in wsgi_app
    response = self.handle_exception(e)
  File "C:\Users\LIC\PycharmProjects\RestAPI\venv\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2070, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()

Comment: File "C:\Users\LIC\PycharmProjects\RestAPI\venv\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1515, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "C:\Users\LIC\PycharmProjects\RestAPI\venv\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1513, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "C:\Users\LIC\PycharmProjects\RestAPI\venv\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1499, in dispatch_request
    return self.ensure_sync(self.view_functions[rule.endpoint])(**req.view_args)

Comment: File "C:\Users\LIC\PycharmProjects\RestAPI\main.py", line 106, in add_cafe
    db.session.add(new_data)
  File "<string>", line 2, in add
    
  File "C:\Users\LIC\PycharmProjects\RestAPI\venv\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\session.py", line 2568, in add
    util.raise_(
  File "C:\Users\LIC\PycharmProjects\RestAPI\venv\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\compat.py", line 207, in raise_
    raise exception
sqlalchemy.orm.exc.UnmappedInstanceError: Class 'builtins.tuple' is not mapped

Comment: Its a 500- internal server error.  I am clueless.

Comment: Did you initialize the db with 'db.create_all()'?

Comment: Thanks. Yes , I did. the error persists sqlalchemy.orm.exc.UnmappedInstanceError: Class 'builtins.tuple' is not mapped

Comment: Thank you for the patience and your responses. I could resolve the issue. The error is due to one additional "," at the end of code creating class instance new_data.

Comment: Cool! Good work resolving it